# I would like to move around 4,000ish folders and combine them with corresponding folders that have a similar name

Tags: files-folders

I would like to move around 4,000ish folders and combine them with corresponding folders that have a similar name.
Example of folder names: 5 TAHOE VIEW COURT

Merge with: 5 Tahoe View Ct_Lot File

and there are many address folders similar to this.

I would prefer a Batch file but a PowerShell command would be good too.

I have tried

```
@Echo off
pushd "C:\path\to\your\base\folder"
for /f "Tokens=1* Delims=-" %%A in (
  'Dir /B /AD *-*'
) Do If Not Exist "%%A" (
  Ren "%%A-%%B" "%%A"
) Else (
  Move /Y "%%A-%%B\*" "%%A\"
  RmDir "%%A-%%B"
)
PopD
```

and

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Variables.

set "rootDir=C:\Users\T450s\Desktop\Merge\"
set "logName=RoboCopy.log"


:: Ensures %rootDir% value contains trailing slash.

if not [%rootDir:~1%] EQU [\] set "rootDir=%rootDir%\"


:: Jumps to the rootDir so that for loop will only display folder names and not the full path.

pushd %rootDir%


:: Loop through all folders located at %rootDir% and for each folder...
::    Use Robocopy.exe to MOVE(and delete original folder) contents of the folder to a new folder named with just first 7 characters of original folder, and delete the original folder.
::    Log the actions of RoboCopy to the screen and also a file called %logName% in the %rootDir% location.

for /d %%a in (*) do (
    set "currentDir=%%a"
    robocopy.exe "%rootDir%%%a" "%rootDir%!currentDir:~0,7!" /MOVE /E /R:3 /W:10 /V /LOG+:%rootDir%%logName% /FP /TEE /XC /XN /XO
)


popd
endlocal

echo.
echo The task has finished.
echo.
pause

:eof
```

Comment: So what is not working in your 2 attempts?

Comment: Is there some type of pattern? Like the first 10 characters are the same for all the folders that should be merged?

Comment: it is not merging when i try it. the only thing that is similar is each folder will have a pair to match with. for example

5740 NORTHBOROUGH DRIVE

5740 Northborough Dr_Lot File

and

1878 Ivycrest Wy_Lot File

1878 IVYCREST WAY